# Are there any differences between the three Jobs.*.Com listings?

Tags: support, jobs

I spend most of my time on SO, and peruse [jobs.stackoverflow.com](http://jobs.stackoverflow.com/) every now and then. But thanks to Meta, I occasionally pop into SF and SU while investigating a question. And so in a recent check at SU, I noticed that the jobs listing was [jobs.joelonsoftware.com](http://jobs.joelonsoftware.com/). So of course I went along and confirmed [jobs.serverfault.com](http://jobs.serverfault.com/).

Now, the three do differ in the header, so that alone is reason enough to have different ones. But do they have different job listings, or are all of the jobs across all 3 the same, just possibly organized differently to cater to the audience of the particular Stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listings on SO and JoS are the same, and SF seems to be more specific when you enter.

Using the search, the listings are the same, but SF shows *System / Network Administration* first.

That's the only difference.

Comment: Satisfactory answer for me. Thanks!